# How to interpret Valgrind output

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

Valgrind yields the following message block:

```
1,065,024 bytes in 66,564 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 21 of 27
   at 0x4C2B800: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
   by 0x40CA21: compute(Parameters&, Array<double>&) [clone .constprop.71] (array.hpp:135)
   by 0x403E70: main (main.cpp:374)
```

How to read this message?

main.cpp line 374 reads:

`results[index] = compute(parameters, weights);`

Is memory leaked exactly at line 374 of main.cpp? Is it leaked in compute() or maybe at assignment/indexing into results?

Comment: How is `compute()` declared?

Comment: what is on array.hpp:135? Leak is probably inside compute function, but I would guess compute is inlined so you won't get the exact line number from valgrind. Pull out the detective hat ;)

Comment: It is declared as: double compute(Parameters &parameters, Array<double> &array)

Comment: array.hpp:135 reads: "elements = new T [size];" where T is the template type and elements is the central member variable of Array.

Comment: Interpret that output the same way you would the call stack. `new[]` allocated the lost memory. `new[]` was called by `compute`. `compute` was called by `main`. So yes, the memory was lost by `main`, but only because `main` started the chain. Ensure that you `delete[]`  the variable you `new[]`ed at array.hpp line 135. If you think you have, Valgrind humbly disagrees.

Comment: OK. I read the comments. Duh. Should have sooner. In `Array`'s destructor make sure you have `delete[] element`. If at any point you replace element, `element = someNewArray;` make sure you first `delete[] element`. Be thorough. Valgrind can tell you where you allocated memory you didn't release, but it can't tell you where you didn't release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is memory leaked exactly at line 374 of main.cpp?

No. It just shows the line number in `main` where the call was made that ultimately leads to the function and line where the memory was allocated.

> Is it leaked in compute() or maybe at assignment/indexing into results?

It says that memory was allocated in `compute()` but was not deallocated in the program before the program exited. That's what constitutes a memory leak.